# zsh and POSIX equivalent of bash's `{var}>&1`

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, posix

Is there an equivalent of `{var}>&1` in `zsh`?

The [`bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) says:

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form `{varname}`. In this case, for each redirection operator except `>&-` and `<&-`, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to `{varname}`. If `>&-` or `<&-` is preceded by `{varname}`, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close.

An example usage of this is capturing `STDERR` from a command:

```
{ error=$( { { ls -ld /XXXX /bin | tr o Z ; } 1>&$tmp ; } 2>&1); } {tmp}>&1
```

How would one do the same in `zsh`, and also in POSIX-land?

I'm after a generic solution, how do I:

- Find the unused file descriptor
- Emulate the `{var}>&1` syntax

Comment: Keep in mind that a redirection like `command 3>&1`, the redirection only applies to `command`, not to the rest of the script; you do **not** have to find an unused descriptor, it doesn't matter if fd `3` is already used in the script. The only way this could break is if a) `command` expects to be passed open fds from the parent process (which is usually well documented) b) `command` expects that the first new fd opened by it will be = 3. To guard against b), use `13>...` or `7` instead of `3`. Many people are [confused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/261469) by this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Support for `{var}>...` was added to `ksh93`, `bash` and `zsh` at the same time on a suggestion of a `zsh` developer. The `{var}>...` operator works in `zsh`, but not for compound commands.

Also note that while in:

```
cmd 3>&1
```

The fd 3 is open only for `cmd`, in

```
cmd {var}>&1
```

The dynamically allocated fd (stored in `$var`) remains open after `cmd` returns in both `zsh` and `bash`. That operator is mostly designed to be used with `exec` (see also `sysopen` in `zsh` for a more straightforward interface to the `open()` system call).

So your code above is missing `exec {tmp}>&-` to release that fd afterwards in `bash`.

So here you could do:

```
if exec {tmp}>&1; then
   errors=$(exec 2>&1 >&"$tmp" {tmp}>&- && ls -ld /x /bin | tr o Z)
   exec {tmp}>&-
fi
```

Which would work in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` and not leak a fd. (the quotes around `$tmp` are only needed in `bash` and when its `posix` option is not enabled). Note that in `ksh93` or when `zsh` or `bash` are in POSIX mode, a failing `exec` causes the shell to exit (`dup()` failing here could be caused by stdout being closed or some limit on number of open files being reached or other pathological cases for which you may want to exit anyway).

But here, you don't need a dynamically allocated fd, just use fd 3 for instance which is not used in that code:

```
{ errors=$(exec 2>&1 >&3 3>&-; ls -ld /x /bin | tr o Z); } 3>&1
```

Which would work in any Bourne-like shell.

Like in the dynamic fd approach above even if it's not as obvious, if the `dup2()` (in `3>&1`) fails, the assignment will not be run, so you may want to make sure `errors` is initialised before  (with a `unset -v errors` for instance).

Note that it doesn't matter whether the fd 3 is otherwise open or in use in the rest of the script (that original fd if open will be left untouched and restored at the end), what matters is whether the code that you are embedded inside the `$(...)` expects fd 3 to be open.

Only fds 0, 1 and 2 are expected to be open by applications, other fds are not. `ls` and `tr` don't expect anything about fd 3. Cases where you may need to use a different fd is when your code *explicitly* makes use of that fd and expects it to have been open beforehand like if instead of `ls`, you had `cat /dev/fd/3` where fd 3 is expected to have been open to  some resource somewhere earlier in your script.

To answer the question on how to assign the first free fd in POSIX shells, I don't think there's a way with the POSIX shell and utilities API. It may also not make sense. The shell may do what it wants internally with any fd provided that doesn't get in the way of its own API. For instance, you may find that fd 11 is free now, but may later be used by the shell for something internal and you writing to it could affect its behaviour. Also note that in POSIX sh, you can only manipulate fds 0 to 9.

Comment: Why are the quotes not needed when `posix` is set in `bash`? 

While you've solved my specific problem, is there a generic way to solve it? (Sorry my initial question wording was not clear)

Comment: @TomHale, POSIX requires split+glob not be enabled in redirection targets when non-interactive. `bash` only does it in POSIX mode. That means the behaviour of `>&$tmp` depends on the value of `$IFS` there. What's not _generic_ in the solutions I suggest?