# emulate bash in zsh breaking dynamically assigned file descriptor

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, io-redirection

I am using a dynamically assigned file descriptor in a script as described in this post:

[zsh and POSIX equivalent of bash's `{var}>&1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472557/zsh-and-posix-equivalent-of-bashs-var1?newreg=e2a5e5fb987a4da9bc95b519d8074033)

The script itself is meant to be portable between bash and zsh, so `emulate -LR bash` is executed early on if the script detects it is being run in zsh.

Unfortunately, this is breaking `exec {fd}>&...`, which has been supported in zsh and bash for quite some time.

To illustrate, this script succeeds (also works in bash):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

set -euo pipefail

for i in {1..10}; do
  exec {fd}> >( tee /dev/stderr | logger )

  echo "FD: ${fd}" >&"${fd}"
done
```

But this does not:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

set -euo pipefail

emulate -LR bash

for i in {1..10}; do
  exec {fd}> >( tee /dev/stderr | logger )

  echo "FD: ${fd}" >&"${fd}"
done
```

`command not found: {fd}`

Can anyone point me to a comprehensive list of what `emulate -R bash` does under the hood (maybe I overlooked it, but I wasn't able to find a real man page for `emulate`). Or better yet if anyone knows which specific option causes this issue, that would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zsh` has no `bash` emulation mode. If you pass `bash` (or anything starting with `s` or `b` (for *Bourne*)) to `emulate`, it will use the `sh` emulation mode:

```
$ emulate bash -c emulate
sh
```

`zsh`'s emulation modes are `zsh` (default), `sh` (initially mostly SysV/Bourne `sh`, now more POSIX `sh`), `csh` and `ksh`.

`bash` is a shell that is mostly POSIX `sh` compliant but with extensions most of which come from the Korn shell, so to have `zsh` interpret `bash` code that is using non-POSIX extensions, your best bet is the ksh emulation (you may want to also enable the `BASH_REMATCH` option intended for `bash` compatibility).

The `{fd}<` feature actually comes from `zsh`. It was implemented at the same time in `zsh`, `ksh93` and `bash` on a suggestion of one of the zsh developers in a discussion between the maintainers of all 3 shells.

`echo {fd}< /dev/null` is required by POSIX to output `{fd}` (though [that's going to change in future versions of the standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1193)), so `zsh` disables it in `sh` emulation. It doesn't in `ksh` emulation, so that's the one you'll want to use here.

As for which option is enabled in which emulation (zsh, sh, ksh, csh), see the `<C>`, `<K>`, `<S>`, `<Z>` next to each option description in the manual (`info zsh 'Description of Options'`).

What option affects the `{fd}>...` feature is specified in the description of that feature in the manual (`info zsh 'file descriptors, use with parameters'`): `IGNORE_BRACES` whose description (`info zsh IGNORE_BRACES`) has a `<S>` next to it meaning it's enabled by default in `sh` emulation only.

Though `zsh` comes with man pages (a few of them), man pages are rather inadequate  for a manual that big. I'd recommend using `info` instead which is hypertext and has a searchable index and table of contents. To learn about `zsh`'s `emulate` builtin, you can run `info zsh emulate`, or from within `info zsh`, press <kbd>I</kbd> for the *index*, and enter `emulate` (tab completion is available). On some systems, you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent as info documentation is not always installed by default.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Not sure where exactly I picked up `emulate bash`, but serves me right for trusting random blogs. It does seem like it would be a worthwhile zsh feature though as now I will need to piece it together myself.

Comment: @oO.o, you'll find that a `bash` emulation mode has been discussed several times on the zsh mailing lists (from as far back as 2001 AFAICS).