# How to use bash syntax in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I've recently switched to zsh mainly for its auto-completion. However, zsh has syntax for scripting different from bash, and I use a lot of ad-hoc one-liners. For example, `echo 'qwe\tasd'` expands the `\t` to tab in zsh but not in bash. I want to keep all the bash syntax while using zsh's auto-completions.

I've tried adding `emulate -LR bash` to my `.zshrc`. However, it seems to break some of my zsh tools, namely [zsh-autocomplete](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) and [starship](https://starship.rs/).

How can I keep my bash syntax while using zsh?

Comment: How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: `bash`'s `echo` expands `\t` as well at least in some builds or some environments. See the `xpg_echo` option in `bash` and the `bsdecho` option in `zsh`. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: `emulate bash` or `emulate  anything-that-starts-with-b` emulates `sh` or the Bourne shell. `emulate ksh` will give you a closer equivalent as `bash` is mostly a Korn-like shell. See also [emulate bash in zsh breaking dynamically assigned file descriptor](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/609795)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments and in [emulate bash in zsh breaking dynamically assigned file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609795/emulate-bash-in-zsh-breaking-dynamically-assigned-file-descriptor), if you want Bash-like behavior in Zsh, you should actually put `emulate ksh` in your `.zshrc` file.